# How does ivy:publish use the [classifier] attribute

Tags: ant, ivy

in ivy:publisher the default deliverivypattern is ${ivy.distrib.dir}/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]

I try to set classifier in my ivy.xml under  by adding attribute e:classifier="" to the  element.

But the [classifier] does not get set?
When ivy:publish runs in my build.xml file it appears to be empty and thereby not included in the file name pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've figured out your problem.

Just to be clear it is the configured resolver that determines the repository filename and not the **publish** task. Here's my example, which utilises two extra attributes **greeting** and **author** in the artifact and ivy filename patterns:

```
<ivysettings>
    <property name="repo.dir" value="${ivy.basedir}/build/repo"/>
    <property name="ivy.checksums" value=""/> <!-- Suppress the generation of checksums -->

    <settings defaultResolver="internal"/>

    <resolvers>
        <filesystem name="internal">
            <ivy pattern="${repo.dir}/[module]/[author]-ivy(-[greeting])-[revision].xml" />
            <artifact pattern="${repo.dir}/[module]/[author]-[artifact]-[greeting]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </filesystem>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

The values of the extra attributes are determined by the *ivy.xml* file:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
  <info organisation="myorg" module="hello" e:author="Mark"/>
  <publications>
    <artifact name="English" ext="txt" type="doc" e:greeting="hello"/>
    <artifact name="Irish" ext="txt" type="doc" e:greeting="dia_dhuit"/>
    <artifact name="Spanish" ext="txt" type="doc" e:greeting="Hola"/>
  </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

Sure enough when I published the files the values of the greeting and author tags were present:

```
$ find build -type f
build/repo/hello/Mark-English-hello-1.0.txt
build/repo/hello/Mark-Irish-dia_dhuit-1.0.txt
build/repo/hello/Mark-Spanish-Hola-1.0.txt
build/repo/hello/Mark-ivy-1.0.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with

> Attribute classifier is not allowed to appear in element 'artifact'

I simply added the "extra" namespace in my declaration and was able to use the classifier.

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd" 
       xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra"> 

    <dependency org="orphans" name="vaadin-timeline-cval" rev="2.0">
        <artifact name="vaadin-timeline-cval" e:classifier="1.3.1" ext="jar"/>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the pattern like so. If the greeting isn't defined it will be left out.

[author]-[artifact](-[greeting])-[revision].[ext]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and we found a way to get the extra attribute in.

my example in the ivysettings.xml look something like...

```
<resolvers>
<filesystem name="internal">
    <ivy pattern="${repo.dir}/[module]/[author]-ivy(-[greeting])-[revision].xml" />
    <artifact pattern="${repo.dir}/[module]/[author]-[artifact]-[greeting]-[revision].[ext]" />
</filesystem>
```

and in your ivy.xml file i put the following: please note that i wanted the greeting value to be dynamic value everytime i publish something (**${someValue}**)

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
<info organisation="myorg" module="hello" e:author="Mark"/>
<publications>
    <artifact name="English" ext="txt" type="doc" e:greeting="${someValue}"/>
</publications>
```

Here is where the trick come in -> In my build file where i call the ivy:publish function, the following attribute have to be set to true (**forcedeliver**)

```
<ivy:publish resolver="@{ivy.resolver}"
         pubrevision="@{publish.revision}"
         status="@{status}"
         forcedeliver="true"
         overwrite="@{overwrite}"
         update="true" />
```

That's it