# How can I add sources of tomcat 6 to an Ivy dependency?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6, ivy, ivyde

I have this setup: Eclipse java project, IvyDE plugin, ivy.xml file in my project, dependency on tomcat 6.0.35 with catalina and other modules, ivy resolvers configured to maven2 ibiblio and other. The catalina module resolves in maven2. But the tomcat 6 artifacts in maven2 do not include tomcat sources. the sources can be found in a zip in apache archives.

I already tried to publish the sources to a team-shared ivy repository, but found no way to do it so that IvyDE classpath container picked it up. We have a team-shared copy of the public catalina and other tomcat modules in our team-shared repository. I thought of manually adding the sources there, but how do I get it right with checksums? Another Idea, create my own catalina-extend project with dependency on public catalina and published artifacts catalina.jar plus source zip? Looks like experimenting another two days... it can't be that difficult??

Comment: Not completely clear what you're trying to do. Source artifacts in Maven are normally managed using "classifiers" a concept that can be supported in ivy using extra attributes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111831/how-to-publish-3rdparty-artifacts-with-ivy-and-nexus/5115447#5115447

Comment: Thanks Mark for your link, it helped me a lot to improve my understanding of maven (although my case is about using, not publishing, maven artifacts in ivy)

Comment: I still don't know what you're trying to do. If you're publishing to a Maven repository then you need to play nice with Maven. If you're publishing to an ivy repository you have lots more flexibility because ivy supports a concept called configurations *and* can store more than one artifact per module. Finally if all you want to do is store stuff in the file system with some custom paths have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280578/how-does-ivypublish-use-the-classifier-attribute/2297379#2297379

Comment: Clarification: I'm trying to use tomcat 6.0.35 in my project, with source. It's that simple. Unfortunately, the implementation of it seems a little more complex...

Comment: Step1: Search public repos for tomcat 6 modules, find catalina and other modules, add deps to my project's ivy file, resolve. Result: tomcat module's jars are in my classpath. Step2: Search public repos for corresponding sources, result: can't find sources in the repos where catalina and other resolved. Step3: Find modules and sources in apache archive, no .pom or .ivy files there. Step4: I downloaded artifacts and source zip, created an .ivy file for this self-made tomcat module, published it to team-shared ivy repository (after posting the question and having a steep learning curve on ivy)