# How to use configuration in Ivy resolver pattern

Tags: build, ivy

In ivysettings.xml I have the following resolver for the artifact:

```
<resolvers>
    <url name="shared" m2compatible="true">
      <artifact pattern="${ivy.shared.default.root}/[orgPath]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision]-[conf].[ext]" />
    </url>
  </resolvers>
```

My ivy.xml file has two configurations and two publications:

```
 <configurations>
    <conf name="debug"/>
    <conf name="release"/>
  </configurations>

  <publications>
    <artifact name="project-debug" type="zip" conf="debug" ext="zip" />
    <artifact name="project-release" type="zip" conf="release" ext="zip"/>
  </publications>
```

In the build.xml I use ivy:publish:

```
<target name="publish" "description="--> publish the project in the ivy repository">
    <property name="revision" value="${project.revision}"/>
    <ivy:publish artifactspattern="${build.dir}/[artifact].[ext]" 
        resolver="shared"
        pubrevision="${revision}"
    />
</target>
```

The filename of the published artifact is not what I would expect:

```
project-1.0-default.zip
```

I would expect two files:

```
project-1.0-release.zip
project-1.0-debug.zip
```

Please note that I cannot use the following pattern:

```
${ivy.shared.default.root}/[orgPath]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
```

That's because the repository I have to use (Archiva) requires the artifact to be of the form [module]-[revision]-... Otherwise we get exceptions like this:

```
Not a valid artifact path in a Maven 2 repository, filename 'project-debug-1.0.zip' doesn't contain version '1.0'.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Updated answer

Take a second look at your resolver:

```
<resolvers>
  <url....>
    <artifact pattern="....../[module]-[revision]-[conf].[ext]" />
  </url>
</resolvers>
```

The two published artefacts would resolve to the same name (because they share the same module and the same publish configuration "default").

Try the following arifact pattern instead:

```
<artifact pattern="....../[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
```

This should yield the following published files:

```
project-debug-1.0.zip
project-release-1.0.zip
```

If you want to add extra optional attributes to the filename consider using [extra attributes](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#extra), for example:

- [Error when trying to use optional token in artifacts pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873991/error-when-trying-to-use-optional-token-in-artifacts-pattern/28886804#28886804)
- [How does ivy:publish use the [classifier] attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280578/how-does-ivypublish-use-the-classifier-attribute/2297379#2297379)

## Old answer

How many files does your build produce? The *artifactpattern* parameter suggests there is only one file?

```
<ivy:publish artifactspattern="${build.dir}/[artifact].[ext]"
```

That would explain why a single file is published.

For examples of how to publish more than one artefact using ivy:

- [good ivy tutorial for local repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200762/good-ivy-tutorial-for-local-repository/2279596#2279596)
- [how to publish 3rdparty artifacts with ivy and nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111831/how-to-publish-3rdparty-artifacts-with-ivy-and-nexus/5115447#5115447)

Comment: I don't think that's correct. Publish task actually does try to publish two artifacts:  
  
[ivy:publish]   published project-debug to http://.../project-9.0-default.zip
[ivy:publish]   published project-release to http://.../project-9.0-default.zip
  
while I would expect:  
  
[ivy:publish]   published project-debug to http://.../project-9.0-**debug**.zip
[ivy:publish]   published project-release to http://.../project-9.0-**release**.zip

Comment: @RoelVZ Updated answer